# Making a list that can be filtered by category/tags

Tags: plugins, customization, filters, lists

I want to create a list of organizations that users can filter by location, service (legal help, federal services, etc.) to create a list of what exact organizations fit their needs. Is there a plug-in that can do this or do I need to write code?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for something like this is probably to use a store locator plugin, [many of which are available for download on WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/store+locator/).

Using their shortcodes you may be able to create a list organizations and filter them by various attributes.

Good luck!